# Dynamic custom template for taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

I want to use dynamic custom templates for taxonomy terms. I have created a vocabulory **myvocab**, Now in this vocabulory i have created an extra field of template in taxonomies that i want to use for its display.

```
function myTheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

 if(arg(0)=='taxonomy' && arg(1)=='term')
    {
        $termLoaded = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));   
        $tmType =   isset($termLoaded->field_template['und'][0]['value']) ?          $termLoaded->field_template['und'][0]['value'] : false;
     if($tmType){

        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]= 'node__taxonomy_'.$termLoaded->field_template['und'][0]['value'];
/*Here template will be node--taxonomy_basic1.tpl.php and 
node--taxonomy_basic2.tpl.php, that i am putting in template folder. But its picking only basic1 template  */
        }
        else{

            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]= 'node__taxonomy';
        }

    }
}
```

I want it dynamic to display its content, so what i am missing in this code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's already working for basic1, did you check if another term really has the value "basic2"?

Comment: I set the basic1 as default value of the select list. And no other template is working. I have tested the values basic2, basic2 and with many other names!